# Binomial Model, Number of nodes from $t = 0$ to $t = n$

Tags: finance, mathematics, quantitative, finance-mathematics

How many paths are there in a binomial model from time $t = 0$ to time $t = n$? How many nodes (states) are there?

Intutively it seems that there are $2^n$ paths and $2n - 1$ nodes. But I am not sure exactly, any suggestions or hints is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will depend on the nature of your tree. For a re-combining binomial tree, the number of nodes, including the initial one, will be
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}.
\end{align*}
For the paths, as at each time $j$, there are two possibilities from each node, the total path number is $2^n$.

Comment: Hey, hate to bug you but could you look at my latest post, I do not understand how we can answer it with knowing the volatility

Comment: I will have a look when I get time